# How to use getAttributeValue() in ClientIdentity for fabric shim?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I am using nodejs sdk for hyperledger fabric, inside my chaincode i need to get name of the identity (sam) who is execting the transaction.

```
{"name":"sam","mspid":"Org1MSP","roles":null,"affiliation":"","enrollmentSecret":"","enrollment":{"signingIdentity":"5aad871581d63447218743ee79289c0c6f531a032d3cf1f0be32083e8c0cbaea","identity":{"certificate":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nRRc9JjnWFvaFaqIJTyNaE7/HFXTXKr+HIkig/UEZpQ==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"}}}
```

I have used the below code

```
async approve(ctx) {
    try {
        const owId = new clientIdentity(ctx.stub).getAttributeValue('name')
        return owId.toString();
     } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error(`Low on amount`);
     }

}
```

but the above code is not returning the name or any other attributes.
Help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

The attributes you retrieve with getAttributeValue() in the Smart Contract are created as follows with the command line:
`fabric-ca-client register --id.name clare --id.secret hursley1 --id.maxenrollments -1 --id.attrs 'department=Finance:ecert,location=Berkshire:ecert'`

So I'm creating 2 attributes for department and location.  Note the `:ecert` on the end which means that I want the attributres written to the certificate, not just stored in the CA database.  Note also that the attributes aren't added to existing certificates, but only "appear" when you have enrolled or renrolled.

Using the node SDK this is a snippet of code that would add the department attribute when registering an Identity:

```
//create user attr array
let registerAttrs = [];
let registerAttribute = {
  name: "department",
  value: "Finance",
  ecert: true
};
registerAttrs.push(registerAttribute);

// at this point we should have the admin user
// first need to register the user with the CA server
return fabric_ca_client.register(
  {
    enrollmentID: username,
    affiliation: "org1",
    role: "client",
    attrs: registerAttrs
  },
  admin_user
);
```

In your smart contract you can then access the attribute:

`ctx.clientIdentity.getAttributeValue('department');`

**Note** that with the fabric-contract-api the clientIdentity object is already populated so you don't need a `new` clientIdentity object.

Comment: i dont want to add new attribute...all i want is just the value of existing attribute?

Comment: I don't think the "name" field is available, but if you use ctx.clientIdentity.getID() you will be returned a long string from which you can extract the CN portion.

Answer (score 1):

You have no attribute named "name". If you analyze your X.509 certificate...

```sh
openssl x509 -text -noout -in yourcert.pem
```

...you get...

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            42:ad:2d:3c:b3:c5:b0:bb:a3:0a:c4:5c:95:97:3d:3c:e9:80:87:a1
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = org1.example.com, CN = ca.org1.example.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 19 05:48:00 2019 GMT
            Not After : Nov 18 05:53:00 2020 GMT
        Subject: OU = client + OU = org1 + OU = department1, CN = sam
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:66:ed:c8:6b:02:f5:03:41:94:ed:19:e6:cb:a6:
                    0f:31:1a:61:1e:26:f0:62:69:5d:6d:9f:f1:09:6f:
                    8e:de:fd:23:30:96:0e:31:b0:15:e3:c0:20:e7:e7:
                    52:88:f3:68:36:eb:d1:51:e0:a6:75:8e:b5:42:0a:
                    52:a4:d5:3c:eb
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                24:7B:F2:24:C1:6C:14:82:62:3C:5A:8E:13:8C:C9:8A:D6:0C:EF:22
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:75:83:FB:11:E6:27:B9:7C:D2:72:D8:5B:AE:F0:E3:E0:5F:B7:26:B9:A1:E0:DF:0F:D7:78:29:77:E7:AA:7D:CD

            1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1: 
                {"attrs":{"hf.Affiliation":"org1.department1","hf.EnrollmentID":"sam","hf.Type":"client"}}
    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:45:02:21:00:97:08:04:37:32:80:8e:99:eb:bb:9e:a3:8e:
         9b:dd:69:c9:09:9a:fe:0f:51:f3:85:a5:8d:a7:a2:e3:ff:ee:
         e8:02:20:3a:45:17:3d:26:39:d6:16:f6:85:6a:a2:09:4f:23:
         5a:13:bf:c7:15:74:d7:2a:bf:87:22:48:a0:fd:41:19:a5
```

Your attribute keys are:

- `hf.Affiliation`
- `hf.EnrollmentID`
- `hf.Type`

There is no "name" attribute. You are probably looking for "**hf.EnrollmentID**".

**EDIT:** You yourself indicated your certificate in your question, in `enrollment.identity.certificate` field. I have only saved...

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICizCCAjGgAwIBAgIUQq0tPLPFsLujCsRclZc9POmAh6EwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw
czELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNh
biBGcmFuY2lzY28xGTAXBgNVBAoTEG9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20xHDAaBgNVBAMT
E2NhLm9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wHhcNMTkxMTE5MDU0ODAwWhcNMjAxMTE4MDU1
MzAwWjBAMTAwDQYDVQQLEwZjbGllbnQwCwYDVQQLEwRvcmcxMBIGA1UECxMLZGVw
YXJ0bWVudDExDDAKBgNVBAMTA3NhbTBZMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHA0IA
BGbtyGsC9QNBlO0Z5sumDzEaYR4m8GJpXW2f8Qlvjt79IzCWDjGwFePAIOfnUojz
aDbr0VHgpnWOtUIKUqTVPOujgdUwgdIwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgeAMAwGA1UdEwEB
/wQCMAAwHQYDVR0OBBYEFCR78iTBbBSCYjxajhOMyYrWDO8iMCsGA1UdIwQkMCKA
IHWD+xHmJ7l80nLYW67w4+Bftya5oeDfD9d4KXfnqn3NMGYGCCoDBAUGBwgBBFp7
ImF0dHJzIjp7ImhmLkFmZmlsaWF0aW9uIjoib3JnMS5kZXBhcnRtZW50MSIsImhm
LkVucm9sbG1lbnRJRCI6InNhbSIsImhmLlR5cGUiOiJjbGllbnQifX0wCgYIKoZI
zj0EAwIDSAAwRQIhAJcIBDcygI6Z67ueo46b3WnJCZr+D1HzhaWNp6Lj/+7oAiA6
RRc9JjnWFvaFaqIJTyNaE7/HFXTXKr+HIkig/UEZpQ==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

...as `yourcert.pem` to check it via openssl.

Comment: But, where should i find .pem file??

Comment: That's the certificate you have indicated in your question, saved into a file: identity.certificate.

Comment: but its not a pem file..and when i excute ur code its shows error

Comment: 'hf.EnrollmentID' inside my getAttributeValue('name') instead of name...but its not returning anything

Comment: Are other parameters (`getID()`, `getMSPID()`) being received suitably? Try to log values before the `return`.

Comment: getID() and getMSPID() is receving properly...but getAttributeName() is not working

Comment: I use regularly the equivalent function in Golang and it works properly. Maybe your client's request source code can help.

Comment: I just used this `clientIdentity.getAttributeValue('hf.EnrollmentID')` when connected with an ID that I registered/enrolled in the CA, and it returned be the "name".  (Identities created by crypotogen such as Admin and User1 do not have the attributes)

Comment: Then your problem is in the client request.